# Julia SimpleWebsockets.jl not working with Julia 1.9.0

Tags: julia

I upgraded to Julia 1.9.0 and SimpleWebsockets appears to no longer work. For example I get:

> LoadError: ConnectError: HTTP.Exceptions.ConnectError

SimpleWebsockets worked fine prior to upgrading to Julia 1.9.0.  I'm not savvy enough with websockets to understand the issue.

Here is code example from SimpleWebsockets that no longer works:

```
using SimpleWebsockets

client = WebsocketClient()
ended = Condition()

listen(client, :connect) do ws
    listen(ws, :message) do message
        @info message
    end
    listen(ws, :close) do reason
        @warn "Websocket connection closed" reason...
        notify(ended)
    end
    for count = 1:10
        send(ws, "hello $count")
        sleep(1)
    end
    close(ws)
end
listen(client, :connectError) do err
    notify(ended, err, error = true)
end

@async 
open(client,"ws://localhost:8080")
wait(ended)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide some minimal code to replicate this behavior (that is see the error message) in Julia 1.9.0?

Comment: Please see code that I just added.

Comment: It seems you are running client without a server and hence the client cannot connect (as there is no server)